# how to use charts package in laravel?

Tags: laravel, charts, laravel-5.6

I want to use a chart package to create a chart using real time data from my database. I tried a package.The link i am providing bellow.But i am not successful.Can anyone provide me a full tutorial about this ?

https://charts.erik.cat/getting_started.html#screenshots

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use charts in your laravel app, I believe you will need to do this in blade view (frontend)

Here are very good JS chat libraries with good documentation

I am currently using
https://www.chartjs.org/

Another good one
http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/

Chart solely for laravel http://lavacharts.com

Check these examples on adminlte
https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/pages/charts/chartjs.html

Another thing, you will need to learn how to use their API. This is universal, everyone has to learn. However, there are a lot of examples you could extract and use as a baseline.

Hope This helped you.

Comment: Lavacharts is framework-agnostic; has some laravel goodies, but you can use it without...

Comment: yes you are right, but the op was asking to be used on laravel so I gave him a suggestion

Comment:  not a problem